# Get source IP from TcpClient

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I need a simple function which takes a TcpClient as a parameter. It is assumed that the the TcpClient is connected to to the server. The function should return the ip being used by the client device for the connection with the server device. Not the ip of the server device with which the connection has been established but the ip of the client device being used for the connection with the server. Since a device can have more than one ip addresses I want the specific ip which is connected with the server.

Comment: And what did you try to find this thing in the documentation? The LocalEndpoint property sort of screams "I could be it" from the name, or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint` holds that information. See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var localEndPoint = tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
var localAddress = localEndPoint.Address;
var localPort = localEndPoint.Port;
```

If you want to get it from the TCP server-side, you should use RemoteEndPoint of course.